# how to write js file like google (with encoding)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a .js file with encoding (the way google writing ga.js file, or similarly formatted js code)

But, no luck. Can anybody give me suggestions on how to go ahead with this?

(or)

How do I write obfuscated JavaScript / what are the best free tools in online to make a .js file like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your quick help yochannah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to achieve JavaScript that looks like this:

[image]

You're looking for a *packer* and *minifier*. See:

- https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/
- http://jscompress.com/
- http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: correct....i want the format like this..thanks for your quick help Zamnuts....

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do it with something like this : http://refresh-sf.com/yui/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to do it manually with tools mentioned previously, or decide to automate the process with tools such as [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) which are server side solutions